# Convert kana full-width number to half-width

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and trying to convert Japanese full-width number to half-width, e.g: `１２３４５` to `12345`. Is there any good way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-kana.php). Ex: convert full-width number to haft-width

```
mb_convert_kana("１２３４５","n")
```

Comment: Great. I just figured out it as well. Thanks a lot.