# How to compare arabic- and kana full-width digits?

Tags: php, character-encoding

How can I compare in PHP the two strings

```
県１９−１県２２５−３県９６−１
```

and

```
県19-1県225-3県96-1
```

?

The first one contains kana full-width numbers, the comparison should treat them as equal to the arabic-numeral.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566991/convert-kana-full-width-number-to-half-width

Comment: @Pang Thanks you. It works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert all the [zen-kaku (fullwidth)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms) characters to their [han-kaku (halfwidth)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms) equivalents first using the [`mb_convert_kana()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-kana.php) function, and then do the comparison, like this:

```
$string1 = "県１９−１県２２５−３県９６−１";
$string2 = "県19-1県225-3県96-1";
var_dump($string1 === $string2);    // This is false because they are different.

// Convert fullwidth to halfwidth.
$string1 = mb_convert_kana($string1, "a");    // Specify "a" for converting both alphabets
$string2 = mb_convert_kana($string2, "a");    // and numbers. See doc for other options.
var_dump($string1 === $string2);    // This becomes true, both are "県19-1県225-3県96-1".
```

Note that [`mb_convert_kana()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-kana.php) is in the *mbstring* extension which is not a default extension, so you may have to [install it first](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php).